# Can't get HttpClient.PostAsync to timeout or cancel at specified times

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying like crazy to get an httpclient to timeout / cancel when I want it to, but it doesn't seem to want to behave.  Perhaps I'm missing something, but I don't see what.

Here's some sample code:

Getting the response:

```
response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(uri, httpContent, cancellationToken)
                                            .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The cancellationToken I'm passing is defined as such:

```
new CancellationTokenSource(1500).Token
```

Elsewhere, the `_httpClient` object has a timeout set to 2 seconds.  So, in theory, the client should timeout in 2 seconds, but the cancellation token should cancel the task in 1.5 seconds.  In debug, this works as expected, until I push to prod (which is under heavy use).  Here's a sample of my output on the server

```
/*
Time    - Time to process - Number of messages received in request

9:21:03 - 0:00:01.4993753 - 32
9:21:09 - 0:00:05.9434192 - A task was canceled.
9:21:09 - 0:00:00.1578903 - 100
9:21:22 - 0:00:12.7766748 - A task was canceled.
9:21:22 - 0:00:00.2524834 - 100
9:21:24 - 0:00:01.5173511 - A task was canceled.
9:21:25 - 0:00:01.1389706 - 100
9:21:26 - 0:00:00.6778574 - 100
9:21:54 - 0:00:28.1702439 - Request timed out
9:21:54 - 0:00:00.0986419 - 100
9:22:03 - 0:00:08.8602139 - Request timed out
9:22:03 - 0:00:00.1110512 - 100
9:22:25 - 0:00:21.3999828 - 100
*/
```

As you can see, some requests are taking over 20 seconds.  Sometimes it works like it should.  This... shouldn't even be possible.  Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Comment: Have a read http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-timeout

Comment: You can **never** cancel **any** task *when you want to*. You can **only** set a cancellation request and the task may or may not cancel its operation because of that request. Only the task itself can decide when/where it is safe/possible to cancel

Comment: Then what about the request timeout?  Why doesn't that work as requested either?